# Two rectangles are inscribed in acute triangle; maximize the ratio of their area to the triangle's area, or show there is no maximum

Tags: geometry, contest-math, geometric-inequalities

From Putnam 1985 A2:

[image: Putnam 1985 A2]

> The problem is attached above.  I'm not sure my solution is entirely rigorous, since I solve it by defining a function which I claim is continuous.  Would a solution like this earn full marks?

---

We will let $b_s, b_r, b_t$ denote the bases of $S, R,$ and $T$ respectively.  Similarly, $h_s, h_r, h_t$ denote the heights of $S, R, $ and $T$ respectively.

By similar triangles, $$b_s = b_t\left(\frac{h_t-h_s-h_r}{h_t}\right), b_r = b_t\left(\frac{h_t-h_r}{h_t}\right).$$

Then, 
\begin{align*}
    \frac{A(R)+A(S)}{A(t)} &= 2\left(\frac{b_rh_r + b_sh_s}{b_th_t}\right) \\
    &= \frac{2}{h_tb_t}\left(b_th_r\left(\frac{h_t-h_r}{h_t}\right) + b_th_s\left(\frac{h_t-h_s-h_r}{h_t}\right)\right) \\
    &= \frac{2}{h_t^2}\left(h_rh_t - h_r^2 +h_sh_t -h_s^2-h_sh_r \right)\\
    &= 2\left(\frac{h_r}{h_t} - \left(\frac{h_r}{h_t}\right)^2 + \frac{h_s}{h_t} - \left(\frac{h_s}{h_t}\right)^2 - \frac{h_sh_r}{h_t^2}\right). \\
\end{align*}
Now, define $\gamma_r = \frac{h_r}{h_t}, \gamma_h = \frac{h_s}{h_t}$.  Note that the values $\gamma_r, \gamma_h$ run continuously in the interval $[0, 1]$, under the condition that $\gamma_r + \gamma_h \le 1$.  Thus, we can define the continuous function $\gamma : R^2 \rightarrow R$ such that $$\gamma(\gamma_s, \gamma_r) = 2(\gamma_s - \gamma_s^2 + \gamma_r-\gamma_r^2 - \gamma_s\gamma_r),$$
corresponding to the ratio $\frac{A(R)+A(S)}{A(T)}$ found above.  It suffices to use the multivariate second derivative test for finding maxima/minima.

First, $\nabla \gamma = \vec{0}$ when $\gamma_r = \gamma_s = 1/3$(note that this satisfies the condition that $\gamma_r + \gamma_s < 1$).

Since $$\det H(\gamma) = \frac{\partial^2\gamma}{\partial\gamma_s^2} \frac{\partial^2\gamma}{\partial\gamma_r^2} - \left(\frac{\partial^2\gamma}{\partial\gamma_s\gamma_r}\right)^2 = (-4)^2 - (-2)^2 = 12 > 0,$$
the critical point $(1/3, 1/3)$ corresponds to a relative maximum.  This corresponding to the value $\gamma(1/3, 1/3) = 2/3$.  Note that this maximum is achievable.  Consider an equilateral triangle with height 3, and $h_r = h_s = 1$.  In this case, $A(T) = \frac{9}{\sqrt{3}}, A(R) = \frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}, A(S) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$, which gives $\frac{A(R) + A(S)}{A(T)} = \frac{2}{3},$ as desired.

Comment: I haven't checked any of your calculations, but $\gamma$ is a polynomial in two variables, so it's not only continuous, but infinitely differentiable.  Your comment, "Note that the values ,ℎ run continuously in the interval [0,1], under the condition that +ℎ≤1," isn't clear to me, though.  On the other hand, you've found a local maximum, but I don't see where you proved that this is a global maximum.

Comment: Your argument is fine, but computing the hessian is useless: you should instead find maxima and minima of $\gamma$ on the boundary ($\gamma_s=0$, $\gamma_r=0$, $\gamma_s+\gamma_r=1$) to prove that $2/3$ is a global maximum.

Comment: saulspatz, Aretino - thanks for the help.